# Size of the optimal base of a LP in Gurobi

Tags: c++, linear-programming, gurobi

I am solving a Linear Program (LP) by calling Gurobi from a C++ program. Let `A` denote the matrix of constraints and `m` the number of constraints, my LP do not satisfy `rank(A)=m`.

My question is, how to get the size of the optimal base after solving the LP with Gurobi?

Comment: Is this a question about how to find the basis size with Gurobi, or a general question about linear programming basis size?

Comment: it is a question about how to find the size with gurobi

Comment: The size of the basis is always m.

Comment: but rank(A) is not equal to m

Comment: Does not matter. A basis consist of a subset of structural and logical variables. So it picks columns from (A I). This matrix B is by construction invertable.

Comment: you mean that Gurobi add new columns to make a base of size m? because the columns of the base should be independent

Comment: You can think of it as having a slack variable for each constraint. These slacks can be in the basis (and in general there will be some rows in the basis).